# Referring to a previously existing DataSet

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I'm working on a very basic VB.net frontend for an Access database and have stumbled upon a problem.

---

```
Dim ds As DataSet
```

MaxRows = ds.Tables("Course_assignmentsDataSet.tblCourse").Rows.Count

i = 0

---

Private Sub Navigate()

```
    txtCourseReference.Text = ds.Tables("Course_assignmentsDataSet.tblCourse").Rows(i).Item(1)
    txtCourseName.Text = ds.Tables("Course_assignmentsDataSet.tblCourse").Rows(i).Item(2)

End Sub
```

---

I get the error that Object Reference is not set to an instance of an Object. I think this is because I haven't defined the DataSet as "Course_assignmentsDataSet"- the one I want to use- but I'm not sure how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset needs to be instantiated using the "New" keyword. The object reference in this case is ds, and it's just set to type dataset. New creates an "instance" of the DataSet.

```
Dim ds as New Course_assignmentsDataSet
```

Then you'll want to do:

```
 txtCourseReference.Text = ds.Tables("tblCourse").Rows(i).Item(1)
 txtCourseName.Text = ds.Tables("tblCourse").Rows(i).Item(2)
```

Edit: As Jay said below, you'll want to [fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171920%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the dataset first

Comment: Of course he'll want to access the data in the DataSet after he'd filled it with data...